# Delete rows in dataframe with letter length 1

Tags: r

I have the following demo code:

```
Name <- c("John", "J", "Bea", "Mike", "D")
Freq <- c("3", "5", "2", "1", "8")
data <- data.frame(Name, Freq)
```

Imagine the dataframe beeing much longer. Now I want to remove every row that only contains a single letter in column data$Name. Probably super simple but i am too stupid.

Answer (score 2):

base solutions

```
Name <- c("John", "J", "Bea", "Mike", "D")
Freq <- c("3", "5", "2", "1", "8")
data <- data.frame(Name, Freq)

# regular square brackets
data[nchar(data$Name) != 1, ]
#>   Name Freq
#> 1 John    3
#> 3  Bea    2
#> 4 Mike    1

# subset with non standard evaluation
# -> no need to use data$ to refer to variables
subset(data, nchar(Name) != 1)
#>   Name Freq
#> 1 John    3
#> 3  Bea    2
#> 4 Mike    1
```